# How to populate one day of data to entire week in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a data for saturday

```
Date           col1       col2       col3
----------     -----      -----     -----
10/06/2017     1.230      2.210     1.067
```

I have this kind of data for every saturday from past 3 years and I need to populate the data to day level granularity as following;

```
Date           col1       col2       col3
----------     -----      -----     -----
04/06/2017     1.230      2.210     1.067    
05/06/2017     1.230      2.210     1.067    
06/06/2017     1.230      2.210     1.067    
07/06/2017     1.230      2.210     1.067    
08/06/2017     1.230      2.210     1.067    
09/06/2017     1.230      2.210     1.067    
10/06/2017     1.230      2.210     1.067
```

Comment: **!!** For dates you should use the **DATE** type and for textual representation you should use the ISO format **YYYY-MM-DD**

Comment: **!!** reserved words (**Date**) should not be used as columns names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  date_add(t.dt,-pe.pos)  as dt
       ,t.col1
       ,t.col2
       ,t.col3

from    mytable t
        lateral view posexplode(split(space(7 - 1),' ')) pe
;
```

---

```
+------------+------+------+------+
|     dt     | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------------+------+------+------+
| 2017-06-10 | 1.23 | 2.21 | 1.07 |
| 2017-06-09 | 1.23 | 2.21 | 1.07 |
| 2017-06-08 | 1.23 | 2.21 | 1.07 |
| 2017-06-07 | 1.23 | 2.21 | 1.07 |
| 2017-06-06 | 1.23 | 2.21 | 1.07 |
| 2017-06-05 | 1.23 | 2.21 | 1.07 |
| 2017-06-04 | 1.23 | 2.21 | 1.07 |
+------------+------+------+------+
```